# Django - NoReverseMatch (admin panel)

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I wrote a function to display a button in the admin panel to parse a file and save questions to the database.
Here's a part of the views.py:

```
def upload_questions_view(request):
    blocks = Blocks.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.FILES.get('questions_file')
        block_id = request.POST.get('block')
        block = Blocks.objects.get(id=block_id)
        if file:
            try:
                parsed_data = parse_excel_survey(file.temporary_file_path())
                for data in parsed_data:
                    if data.type == "ask":
                        ask = Asks(
                            position=data.cl1,
                            block=block,  
                            ask=data.question,
                            important=data.cl3,
                            answerable=data.answerable,
                            multiplier=data.cl5,
                        )
                        ask.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Data uploaded!')
            except Exception as e:
                messages.error(request, f'Error: {e}')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'File error.')
        return redirect('admin:main_asks_changelist')
    context = {
        'blocks': blocks
    }
    return render(request, 'admin/upload_questions.html', context)
```

Here's the change_list_template.html:

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block object-tools-items %}
    <li>
        <a href="{% url 'admin:upload_questions' %}" class="addlink">
            {% trans "Upload Excel" %}
        </a>
    </li>
    {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

Here's a part of admin.py:

```
class AsksAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [CriteriesInline]
    list_filter = ('block', 'ask', 'position', 'important', 'multiplier')
    list_display = ('block', 'ask', 'position', 'important', 'multiplier')
    change_list_template = 'admin/change_list_with_upload.html'

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        custom_urls = [
            path('upload_questions/', self.admin_site.admin_view(upload_questions_view), name='upload_questions'),
        ]
        return custom_urls + urls
def upload_questions(self, request):
    return redirect('admin:upload_questions')
upload_questions.short_description = "Download Excel"
actions = [upload_questions]
```

A button to upload files appeared in the admin panel, but there's an error related to the user side of the application, specifically with the side menu(sidebar.html):
NoReverseMatch at /admin/main/asks/upload_questions/
Reverse for 'quant_page' with keyword arguments '{'fin_id': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['quant/(?P<fin_id>[0-9]+)$']
Here's a part of sidebar.html

```
      </li>
      <li class="mb-1">
         <a href="{% url 'quant_page' fin_id=fin_objects.pk %}" class="link-body-emphasis d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">
          <img src="{% static 'img/report7.svg' %}" class="icon-image" >
          <span style="margin-left: 5px; white-space: nowrap;"> Quanities</span>
        </a>
     </li>
      <li class="mb-1">
        <a href="{% url 'report' fin_id=fin_objects.pk %}" class="link-body-emphasis d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">
          <img src="{% static 'img/report7.svg' %}" class="icon-image" >
          <span style="margin-left: 5px; white-space: nowrap;"> Report</span>
        </a>
    </li>
```

While working on the client side, there is no error when interacting with the side menu. When navigating to the quant_page, the page works as expected. I can't understand why an error from the external part occurs when interacting with the admin.

Comment: and what is `fin_objects`?

Comment: "fin_objects is an instance of the Fins model in our application, representing entities we assess. The model has attributes like name_fins and a one-to-one relation with the User model. In the sidebar, we use its primary key to create links, such as to the quant_page."
class Fins(models.Model):
    name_fins = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

Comment: @KamiaAbdulkarimova: but where exactly injects  that object in the template?